# How can I create a lstm cell with only single time step in tensorflw?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

```
layer_1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=layer_c, units=512, activation=tf.nn.tanh, name='layer1')

layer_2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=1, units=512, activation=tf.nn.tanh, name='layer2')
```

Here my layer_2 output is [batch_size,512]. I need to send this layer_2 output through a single lstm unit. But when I tried **tf.nn.static_rnn** it gives an error saying my input should be a sequence. How can I perform this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation for `static_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/static_rnn), the `inputs` argument is expecting a list:

> **`inputs`: A length T list** of inputs, each a Tensor of shape [batch_size, input_size], or a nested tuple of such elements.

In your case, `T==1`, so you can just pass it a single-element list containing your previous layer. To keep track of the internal cell and hidden states in such a way that you can keep them across timesteps, you can add additional placeholders and pass them to the `static_rnn` using the `initial_state` attribute. Because `cell.state_size` is a tuple for LSTM cells (of `(cell_state, hidden_state)`), we have to pass a tuple for this attribute, and a tuple will be returned for the output state.

Here is a minimal working example based on your code, just feeding placeholders of ones for the input at each timestep and tracking the internal states across time:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


num_timesteps = 6
batch_size = 3
num_input_feats = 100
num_lstm_units = 5

lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_lstm_units)


input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_input_feats], name='input')

input_c_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, lstm_cell.state_size.c], name='c_state')
input_h_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, lstm_cell.state_size.h], name='h_state')

layer_1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=input_x, units=512, activation=tf.nn.tanh, name='layer1')
layer_2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=layer_1, units=512, activation=tf.nn.tanh, name='layer2')

layer_2_next, next_state = tf.nn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, [layer_2], dtype=tf.float32,
                                            initial_state=(input_c_state, input_h_state))

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

  # initialize the internal cell state and hidden state to zero
  cur_c_state = np.zeros([batch_size, lstm_cell.state_size.c], dtype="float32")
  cur_h_state = np.zeros([batch_size, lstm_cell.state_size.h], dtype="float32")


  for i in range(num_timesteps):

    # here is your single timestep of input
    cur_x = np.ones([batch_size, num_input_feats], dtype="float32")

    y_out, out_state = sess.run([layer_2_next, next_state],
                                feed_dict={input_x: cur_x,
                                           input_c_state: cur_c_state,
                                           input_h_state: cur_h_state})
    cur_c_state, cur_h_state = out_state   # pass states along to the next timestep

    print (y_out)  # here is your single timestep of output
```

Comment: one more thing- so here during each iteration what is the initial state of the lstm cell. Since this works in a feed-forward manner will this keep a memory during each iteration?

Comment: The initial state is typically zero, and you either reset it to the initial value or pass the previous state at every iteration, depending on your input sequences. Usually when training an RNN you would back propagate across multiple timesteps and so having your graph output a single timestep at once probably isn't a good idea for training. But for after training, it's the only way to use the model. I updated the example in the answer to keep track of the internal memory across iterations. Please let me know if anything is still unclear and I will update it some more.